# SQL Server 2008 R2 Replication not working - my 1st try

Tags: sql-server, replication

[image: screenshot]I am having difficulties when I attempt my first shot at SQL Server 2008 R2 Replication.
Looks like I have login issues.
How do you modify settings without having to start a new plan again?
Please be kind - this is all new to me ....... lol

It looks like I have a security problem:

> Access to path is denied

Answer (score 2):

Your Snapshot Agent process account does not have sufficient permissions to access the snapshot folder.

In the section ***Permissions That Are Required by Agents*** in [Replication Agent Security Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx), the Snapshot Agent process account requires db_owner in the distribution and publication databases and needs read, write, and modify permissions on the snapshot share.

Have a look at [Lesson 2: Preparing the Snapshot Folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337500.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Still having problems. I thought I could use the sa account for the agent process. Still fails on same error.

Comment: Did you set the permissions on the snapshot folder?  The Snapshot Agent process account requires read, write, and modify permissions.

Comment: I suggest that you trust the error text - when it writes `Access to the path is denied` then usually access is really denied. SA account is not Windows account - check your Windows permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would also say bang it out in your test environment as well. Make sure you have Ip connectivity as well as name resolution too.